# T-SQL SELECT TOP Value and increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012. I have the following table:

```
Id | SalesAreaId | CollectionId 
---+-------------+-----------
1  |     12      |     1
2  |     7       |     1
3  |     5       |     1
```

I want to select the highest `CollectionId` and increment it +1.

```
DECLARE @CollectionId INT = 1;

SELECT TOP 1 @CollectionId = [CollectionId]
FROM [MyProject].[Sales]
WHERE [CollectionId] = MAX([CollectionId])

@CollectionId = @CollectionId + 1
```

As a result the next `@CollectionId` should be 2, unfortunately this doesn't really work...

Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you want as the result?

Comment: The next @CollectionId should be 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write this as:

```
SELECT @CollectionId = MAX([CollectionId])
FROM [MyProject].[Sales];
```

Normally, you would do the increment in the `SELECT` *and* take into account an empty table:

```
SELECT @CollectionId = COALESCE(1 + MAX([CollectionId], 1)
FROM [MyProject].[Sales];
```

Comment: Superbe, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CollectionId INT = 1;
SELECT @CollectionId  = ((SELECT MAX(CollectionId) FROM [MyProject].[Sales])+1);
```

increments the last collectionid with one if the last collectionid is the largest of all collectionids

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Your answer is in the moderation queue because it has been flagged as low-quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can SELECT simply as follows

```
SELECT TOP 1 (CollectionId + 1)
FROM Sales
ORDER BY CollectionId DESC
```